# How possible would it be for an attacker to sniff the pairing process in Classic Bluetooth?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

Classic Bluetooth protects its connection by keeping the pairing process secret. How does Classic Bluetooth prevent the keys from being sniffed during the pairing process? On what channel does the pairing process occur?